# Error writing column of string containing integers and spaces to Oracle SQL with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, sqlalchemy

I am trying to write a column of strings of integers and spaces to an Oracle SQL database. When this column is not present, no error when writing. The pandas dataframe looks like this:

** apologies about the code appearance, I feel like I described the problem and attempts I've made well enough that it's unnecessary to see the code snippets. It would take me another half hour to clean up the poorly formatted newline situation that happened when I copied it over. ***** i cleaned up the most informative parts***** In the stackoverflow question editor, the spacing looked perfect so i didn't realize it would turn out as gobbledegook when posted.

The main important thing in the code snippets is the error message afaik:
`sqlalchemy.exc.NotSupportedError: (cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError) Python value of type numpy.int64 not supported.`

**

```
>>> df
                          some_id      another_col    some_min    some_max  \
0        xxxyyyasdf;adfsa;dafafda       valuesdfaa           0           1
1                         sadfaaa     anothervalue           3           9
2                         dfjlkjl othersmallstring           3           5
...                           ...              ...         ...         ...
15289                    eruoiwee         somevalu           1           7
15290                     dfasdfi       somevaluee           0           1    

some_median        some_timestamp   p1_value   p3_value  \
0                  1            2022-09-05          1          1
1                  7            2021-10-16          7          8
2                  4            2021-08-09          3          4
...              ...                   ...        ...        ...
15289              4            2022-09-05          2          5
15290              1            2022-09-05          1          1

                                       column_of_strings
0      1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
1      3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
2      3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
...                                                  ...
15289  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
15290  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

When I include this column of string, I get this error. It is insanely unhelpful, as usual for Oracle SQL errors so no surprise there:

```
>>> df.to_sql(tbl_name, conn, if_exists='replace', dtype=dtypes, index=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "......./lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1788, in _execute_context                                                                                                            self.dialect.do_executemany(                                                                                                                                                                                                                  File "......./lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/oracle/cx_oracle.py", line 1360, in do_executemany                                                                                                cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)                                                                                                                                                                                                   cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Python value of type numpy.int64 not supported.
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "......./lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2878, in to_sql                                                                                                                         return sql.to_sql(                                                                                                                                                                                                                            File "......./lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 769, in to_sql                                                                                                                                return pandas_sql.to_sql(                                                                                                                                                                                                                     File "......./lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1920, in to_sql                                                                                                                               total_inserted = sql_engine.insert_records(                                                                                                                                                                                                   File "......./lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1470, in insert_records                                                                                                                       raise err                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     File "......./lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1461, in insert_records                                                                                                                       return table.insert(chunksize=chunksize, method=method)                                                                                                                                                                                       File "......./lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1023, in insert                                                                                                                               num_inserted = exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)                                                                                                                                                                                            File "......./lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 929, in _execute_insert                                                                                                                       result = conn.execute(self.table.insert(), data)                                                                                                                                                                                              File "......./lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1295, in execute                                                                                                                     return meth(self, multiparams, params, _EMPTY_EXECUTION_OPTS)        
File "......./lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 325, in _execute_on_connection                                                                                                      return connection._execute_clauseelement(                                                                                                                                                                                                     File "......./lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1487, in _execute_clauseelement                                                                                                      ret = self._execute_context(                                                                                                                                                                                                                  File "......./lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1851, in _execute_context                                                                                                            self._handle_dbapi_exception(                                                                                                                                                                                                                 File "......./lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2032, in _handle_dbapi_exception                                                                                                     util.raise_(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  File "......./lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_                                                                                                                       raise exception                                                                                                                                                                                                                               File "......./lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1788, in _execute_context                                                                                                            self.dialect.do_executemany(
File "......./lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/oracle/cx_oracle.py", line 1360, in do_executemany
cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.NotSupportedError: (cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError) Python value of type numpy.int64 not supported.
```

I have tried using CLOB and VARCHAR with all the string lengths above and below the 3999 character limit in the case of CLOB, and below in the case of VARCHAR. Incase it matters, the dtypes are below, but they aren't changing between when I include the troublesome column and when I don't (except the one column is omitted from dtypes when I don't include it in the table):

```
>>> pprint(dtypes)
{'some_id': VARCHAR(length=43),
'some_max': INTEGER(),
'some_timestamp': DateTime(),
'some_median': INTEGER(),
'some_min': INTEGER(),
'p1_value': INTEGER(),
'p3_value': INTEGER(),
'another_col': VARCHAR(length=11)}

# and as i mentioned, this one is either VARCHAR or CLOB
'column_of_strings': CLOB() / VARCHAR(length=greater_than_longest_string)
```

I have obviously checked, over and over, the dtypes of the dataframe, python type of the row values, etc. I have tried enforcing the column dtypes on the dataframe with `df[inttypecolumns].astype(int)` and `df[stringtypecolumns].astype(str)` where appropriate. `type(df['column_of_strings'].iloc[row]) -> str` as expected for every row.

One further confusing thing I've noticed is that if I have this column in the dataframe, and then drop it before writing, I get the same error. If I don't attach the column to the dataframe, I avoid the error and the write happens successfully.

The error makes no sense to me given that when I try adding the column of strings, it's telling me that there's some complaint about numpy int values. There are no numpy int value in the dataframe. Furthermore, I feel pretty certain you can write columns of numpy ints (and python ints and the special nullable pandas ints as well) to Oracle SQL, and that I've done that thoughtlessly many, many times. I'm not an expert in sqlalchemy or Oracle SQL, nor do I want to be (the SQL world seems unnecessarily difficult to achieve goals that simply work in many other database paradigms). I just want to understand if there is a solution to this issue.

Comment: Have you tried using [oracledb](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/oracle.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle.oracledb) instead of cx-Oracle? FWIW, [this code](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/09fd7c8c5cbc45fc01cf90b56f842853) works fine for me. Please try to create a [mcve] to illustrate your issue.

Comment: I haven't heard of that, I thought cx oracle was the driver library we had to use. If it doesn't work I can write an example where I init a dataframe I suppose, I'm not sure what else is missing...  in the real case the minimum example that captures how this dataframe is created would be not trivial at all.

Comment: A big part of the value in creating a [mcve] is that it helps pin down the actual cause of the problem, which may be slightly different than we think it is. Assuming that my example code does work for you (ruling out an environment issue like driver, database version, SQLA/pandas version, etc.) it does show that simply inserting a string like `1 2 3 4 5 …` into a CLOB column is not the actual problem in itself.

Comment: upgrading to oracledb gives a slightly altered error, gist of it seems the same. I'm going to try Christopher's answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

In my 'things we should improve in python-oracledb' notes I have this snippet that may help:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:

    sql = "select level from dual connect by level <= 10"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())

    bnd = []
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        # without the cast, get "DPY-3002: Python value of type "int64" is not supported"
        bnd.append((row[0].astype('float64'),))

    cursor.executemany("insert into t (c1) values (:1)", bnd)
```

This is with [python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a), which is the new name for the latest release of cx_Oracle.

Comment: The cast is not required if we simply do `df.to_sql("t", engine, …)`. The DataFrame has a column whose `Dtype` is `int64`, but pandas and SQLAlchemy apparently figure out how to work around the issue.

Comment: I've been able to work around the issue by excluding columns that have integer values *when* I include this string (CLOB) column of integer and space characters. But it still begs the question, why does including a CLOB column (it clearly should be irrelevant what the content of the string is, it just happens to be a string with integers...) cause perfectly normal integer columns to throw an error? I am just as bewildered as ever, though I have my data in a slightly less desirable split between two tables.